# My Angular2 website doesnt update using Angular2-cli

Tags: terminal, npm, angular, angular-cli

Im building small app in angular2 and im trying to modify a file using webstorm to see if its updating in my browser.

I did the following and got no errors so far:

```
npm i -g angular-cli
ng new ponyracer
ng serve   (working on background)
```

In this file, I changed "PonyRacer4566" to "dshbhs" But nothing gets update in the browser.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'ponyracer-app',
    template: '<h1>PonyRacer4566</h1>'
})
export class PonyRacerApp {
}
```

Comment: Have you checked developer tools -> console for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add these lines to my index.html in order to get this working;

```
<script src="vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>

  <script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a bad idea becouse you load all the liberies insed what you need.